# CSS :not(:first-of-type) isn't working on div but works on other elements

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am creating an accordion in which the first element is open. Crediting the code [here](https://codepen.io/yukinouz1/pen/Mdxqqx).

The main modification to this code is that I wanted to put some subtext under the main title, so I created a div and wrapped the h2 and h3 inside of it. You can see my HTML, CSS, and JS below:

```js
$(function() {
  $(".accordion-content:not(:first-of-type)").css("display", "none");
  $(".js-accordion-title:first-of-type").addClass("open");

  $(".js-accordion-title").click(function() {
    $(".open").not(this).removeClass("open").next().slideUp(300);
    $(this).toggleClass("open").next().slideToggle(300);
  });
});
```

```css
.accordion-title {
  border-top: 1px solid #BEBEBE;
  padding: 2em 0;
  background: #F7F7F7;
}

.accordion-container .accordion-title h2  {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #F7F7F7;
  font-size: 32px;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #DA15B6;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-bottom: .125em;
}

.accordion-container .accordion-title h3 {
  background-color: #F7F7F7;
  font-size: 18px;
  letter-spacing: 0.9px;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #000;
  text-align: center;
}

.price-number {
  font-size: 25px;
  letter-spacing: 0.54px;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.accordion-container .accordion-title h2::after {
  content: '3';
  position: absolute;
  right: 25px;
  bottom: -10px;
  font-size: 1.3em;
}
.accordion-container .accordion-title.open h2::after {
  content: '2';
  position: absolute;
  right: 25px;
  bottom: -10px;
  font-size: 1.3em;
}

/*CSS for CodePen*/

.accordion-content {
  padding-left: 2.3125em;
}
.accordion-container {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="accordion" class="accordion-container">
  <div class="accordion-title js-accordion-title">
    <h2 class="price-plan-name">Standard</h2>
    <h3 class="starting-price">Starting at
      <span class="price-number">$1,650</span></h3>
  </div>
  <div class="accordion-content">
    <p>Accordion Content1</p>
  </div>
  <div class="accordion-title js-accordion-title">
    <h2>Pro</h2>
    <h3 class="accordion-subtitle">Starting at
      <span class="price-number">$2,950</span></h3>
  </div>
  <div class="accordion-content">
    Accordion Content2
  </div>
  <div class="accordion-title js-accordion-title">
    <h2>Elite</h2>
    <h3 class="accordion-subtitle">Starting at
      <span class="price-number">$3,950</span></h3>
  </div>
  <div class="accordion-content">
    Accordion Content3
  </div>
</div>
```

The issue I am having is trying to have the first accordion-content opened on page load. This should be achievable with the first line of JS, "$(".accordion-content:not(:first-of-type)").css("display", "none");" but it doesn't seem to work. I believe it has to do with a conflict between the div "accordion-title" and div "accordion-content". If I change "accordion-content" to have a p or h5 tag for example, the code will work properly. Are there any suggestions on how I could work around this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `<div class="accordion-content">` matches `.accordion-content`, it is a `div`, it is the second div in the parent so it matches `:not(:first-of-type)`. Did you expect `:first-of-type` to mean "first thing that matches the other selectors combined with this one"?

Comment: @Quentin I think the idea of the `:not(:first-of-type)` is that the all of the `accordion-content` with the exception of the first should have a `display: none`. I approached it the same way the original codepen was written.

Comment: No. `:not(:first-of-type)` means "not the first element, in the parent element, of the same type", and that type is `div`.

Comment: I see, that breaks down the meaning of `:not(:first-of-type)` much easier for me to understand. As @Huangism suggested, changing to pseudo class to `:first` worked for this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of type targets the first div(in your case) in the parent, not based on the class you provided so it would not work as you would expect

You can use this instead

`$( ".accordion-content:not( :first )" ).css( "display", "none" );`

or you could just set them all to display none in css and either open the first one with js or with a class in css and add that class in js or markup

```js
$(function() {
  $(".accordion-content:not(:first)").css("display", "none");
  $(".js-accordion-title:first-of-type").addClass("open");

  $(".js-accordion-title").click(function() {
    $(".open").not(this).removeClass("open").next().slideUp(300);
    $(this).toggleClass("open").next().slideToggle(300);
  });
});
```

```css
.accordion-title {
  border-top: 1px solid #BEBEBE;
  padding: 2em 0;
  background: #F7F7F7;
}

.accordion-container .accordion-title h2  {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #F7F7F7;
  font-size: 32px;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #DA15B6;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-bottom: .125em;
}

.accordion-container .accordion-title h3 {
  background-color: #F7F7F7;
  font-size: 18px;
  letter-spacing: 0.9px;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #000;
  text-align: center;
}

.price-number {
  font-size: 25px;
  letter-spacing: 0.54px;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.accordion-container .accordion-title h2::after {
  content: '3';
  position: absolute;
  right: 25px;
  bottom: -10px;
  font-size: 1.3em;
}
.accordion-container .accordion-title.open h2::after {
  content: '2';
  position: absolute;
  right: 25px;
  bottom: -10px;
  font-size: 1.3em;
}

/*CSS for CodePen*/

.accordion-content {
  padding-left: 2.3125em;
}
.accordion-container {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="accordion" class="accordion-container">
  <div class="accordion-title js-accordion-title">
    <h2 class="price-plan-name">Standard</h2>
    <h3 class="starting-price">Starting at
      <span class="price-number">$1,650</span></h3>
  </div>
  <div class="accordion-content">
    <p>Accordion Content1</p>
  </div>
  <div class="accordion-title js-accordion-title">
    <h2>Pro</h2>
    <h3 class="accordion-subtitle">Starting at
      <span class="price-number">$2,950</span></h3>
  </div>
  <div class="accordion-content">
    Accordion Content2
  </div>
  <div class="accordion-title js-accordion-title">
    <h2>Elite</h2>
    <h3 class="accordion-subtitle">Starting at
      <span class="price-number">$3,950</span></h3>
  </div>
  <div class="accordion-content">
    Accordion Content3
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This works perfectly. I was thinking there must be a way to edit that pseudo class to achieve what I wanted. And the alternative suggestion works as well. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

`.hide()` all `.accordion-content`, then add `.open` to the `.first()` `.js-accordion-title` and `.show()` the `.first()` `.accordion-content`

```js
$(function() {
  $('.accordion-content').hide();
  $(".js-accordion-title").first().addClass('open').next().show();
  $(".js-accordion-title").click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("open").next().slideToggle(300);
  });
});
```

```css
.accordion-container div.accordion-content:first-of-type {
  background: red;
}

.accordion-title {
  border-top: 1px solid #BEBEBE;
  padding: 2em 0;
  background: #F7F7F7;
}

.accordion-container .accordion-title h2  {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #F7F7F7;
  font-size: 32px;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #DA15B6;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-bottom: .125em;
}

.accordion-container .accordion-title h3 {
  background-color: #F7F7F7;
  font-size: 18px;
  letter-spacing: 0.9px;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #000;
  text-align: center;
}

.price-number {
  font-size: 25px;
  letter-spacing: 0.54px;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.accordion-container .accordion-title h2::after {
  content: '3';
  position: absolute;
  right: 25px;
  bottom: -10px;
  font-size: 1.3em;
}
.accordion-container .accordion-title.open h2::after {
  content: '2';
  position: absolute;
  right: 25px;
  bottom: -10px;
  font-size: 1.3em;
}

/*CSS for CodePen*/

.accordion-content {
  padding-left: 2.3125em;
}
.accordion-container {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="accordion" class="accordion-container">
  <div class="accordion-title js-accordion-title">
    <h2 class="price-plan-name">Standard</h2>
    <h3 class="starting-price">Starting at
      <span class="price-number">$1,650</span></h3>
  </div>
  <div class="accordion-content">
    <p>Accordion Content1</p>
  </div>
  <div class="accordion-title js-accordion-title">
    <h2>Pro</h2>
    <h3 class="accordion-subtitle">Starting at
      <span class="price-number">$2,950</span></h3>
  </div>
  <div class="accordion-content">
    Accordion Content2
  </div>
  <div class="accordion-title js-accordion-title">
    <h2>Elite</h2>
    <h3 class="accordion-subtitle">Starting at
      <span class="price-number">$3,950</span></h3>
  </div>
  <div class="accordion-content">
    Accordion Content3
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```